# two different processrequests on one httphandler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

can i make two different

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

and

```
public void ProcessRequest2(HttpContext context)
```

methods on the same httphandler so i can handle different data?

(i post it through jQuery json)

Comment: Please do not use tags in titles.  Please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: why not simply create 2 unique handlers.

Comment: how the two requests will differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid creating two methods,

`IHttpHandler` contains just one `ProcessRequest`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx

Nota : you can create two handlers